# Strapi. How can I have a default value in the relations type field?

Tags: strapi

I'm in an environment where I have `Content-Types` like `Post` and `User`. When I set a relation between these two elements, for example `many posts related to one user`, I can associate a user with the post he wrote. How can I go about having this mandatory value so that the user field is always full? Is it possible to use a default value?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

setup a relation as required is not something you can do with Strapi.

At least, for now. We have an issue open about this topic https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/557

If you want to auto-apply the authenticated user as author for your entry, there is a guide here that explains how to do it - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/is-owner.html

If you want to do that with your admin panel, you will have to customize the admin of the content manager plugin.
Using the customization concept - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a lifecycle hook to add a default value or make a relation field mandatory

```
const Boom = require('boom');
module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    async beforeUpdate(params, data) {
      if (data.category == null) {
        throw Boom.badRequest('Category is required!');
      }
    }
  }
};
```